# Blur event creates endless loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a web form, I have a question that the user must answer.  However, the code below is problematic in that when the user clicks to remove the alert, it fires the blur event again and creates an endless loop.

```
$('#selPregnant').on('blur', function() {
    if ($("#selGender :selected").val() === "F") {
        if($("#selPregnant").val()===''){
            alert('If the individual is female, the pregnancy question MUST be answered.');
            $('#selPregnant').focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

How do I show the alert and set focus back on the question without triggering the blur again?

Comment: The standard browser here is Edge, not Chrome.

Comment: Edge is a Chromium-based browser.

Comment: Edge practically is Chrome these days, try the suggestions in the link.

Comment: Your issue is the `alert()` - this steals the focus (firing blur).  The best option is to remove the `alert` and use a better UX component.

Comment: How is `$("#selGender :selected")` different from `$("#selGender").val()` ? If the element wth `selGender` is a select, which I would expect due to the ID, then a simpler code would be: `$("#selGender").on("change", (e) => $("#selPregnant").prop("required", e.target.value === "F"));` assuming the selGender default value is empty as it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if I set the focus afterwards, outside the JavaScript [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop).

```js
$('#selPregnant').on('blur', function() {
    if ($("#selGender :selected").val() === "F") {
        if($("#selPregnant").val()===''){
            alert('If the individual is female, the pregnancy question MUST be answered.');
            setTimeout(() => $('#selPregnant').focus(), 0);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selGender"><option value="F" selected="selected">Female</option></select>
<br>
<input type="text" id="selPregnant" />
```